# Python Pandas - (not working) Extracting from csv into other csvs using dataframes and drop

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

Python 2.7
Pandas 0.16.2

I have a CSV which contains lots of information regarding computers.
I have created a program in python with pandas to extract them into new CSVs regarding their data fits within different criterion.
I use the same technique for other extraction needs in the same program script, and that works.
I'm using the same main dataframe and dropping the entries once the extraction has been achieved.

In this instance, I am trying to extract entries that have an " OR " value somewhere in their 'Discovered OS' field e.g. it might be "Windows 2000 OR Windows Vista".

I am also trying to keep the columns and indexes the same, so when I extract the CSV I can then drop the data from the main dataframe. This means I can continue in processing the remaining data.

The output seems to extract server123 and others like it, but server123 does not have " OR " in its  'discovered OS' field.

In the server123  'discovered OS' field, it has: 
"Linux 3.0 - 3.9"

Please review the below code and please can you help me discern the issue:

```
unknown_idents = ["unix","linux","windows","cisco","hp ","citrix","hypervisor","bsd"]

dframe = pd.read_csv(scriptDir + "\\thefile.csv")



testSee = dframe[dframe['Hostname'].str.contains("server123")]

testSee.to_csv( dirOfOutput + "\\test_see_if_server123_in_13.csv")

print "SERVER123 INDEX=" + str(testSee.index)

#---11) Uncertains: with "OR" in the Discovered OS



#--- for unknown_dev in unknown_idents:

    uncertainDF = pd.DataFrame(dframe[dframe['Discovered OS'].str.contains(unicode(' OR ',"utf-8"), case=False)],index=dframe[dframe['Discovered OS'].str.contains(unicode(' OR ',"utf-8"), case=False)].index,columns=dframe[dframe['Discovered OS'].str.contains(unicode(' OR ',"utf-8"), case=False)].columns)

    uncertainDF.to_csv( dirOfOutput + "\\UncertainDF.csv")

    testSee = uncertainDF[uncertainDF['Hostname'].str.contains("server123")]

    testSee.to_csv( dirOfOutput + "\\test_see_if_server123_in_13a.csv")

    uncertainDF2 = pd.DataFrame(uncertainDF[uncertainDF['Discovered OS'].str.contains(unknown_dev, case=False)],index=uncertainDF[uncertainDF['Discovered OS'].str.contains(unknown_dev, case=False)].index,columns=uncertainDF[uncertainDF['Discovered OS'].str.contains(unknown_dev, case=False)].columns)

    uncertainDF2.to_csv( dirOfOutput + "\\UncertainDF2_" + str(unknown_dev) + ".csv")

    testSee = uncertainDF2[uncertainDF2['Hostname'].str.contains("server123")]

    testSee.to_csv( dirOfOutput + "\\test_see_if_server123_in_13b.csv")

    if len(uncertainDF2.index) > 0:

        uncertainDF2.to_csv(dirOfOutput + "\\_uncertain_" + unknown_dev  + ".csv", sep=',', columns=outcols)

        print uncertainDF2.index

        dframe = dframe.drop(uncertainDF2.index)



testSee = dframe[dframe['Hostname'].str.contains("server123")]

testSee.to_csv( dirOfOutput + "\\test_see_if_server123_in_14.csv")
```

Comment: Step 1: Fix your code.  I would start with checking your quotes.

Comment: Done. I don't know why the quotation mark on line 4 was missing here. Thanks for spotting it though. Two eyes are better than one.

Comment: Can you also please post a sample of your input or the dataframe dframe